# org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Connection to the database terminated

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, nosql, spring-data-neo4j

I want to connect Spring Boot with neo4j database, however, it returns an error like that. It says that the connection has been terminated. The error is as follow:

`org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.ServiceUnavailableException: Connection to the database terminated.`

This is my Controller

```
@RequestMapping("/neo4j/Movie")
public class MovieController {

    private final MovieRepository movieRepository;

    public MovieController(MovieRepository movieRepository) {
        this.movieRepository = movieRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping("/graph")
    public List<Movie> graph() {
        return (List<Movie>) movieRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

This is my Repository

```
@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends Neo4jRepository<Movie,Long> {

    @Query("MATCH(m:Movie)<-[relation:ActedIn]-(b:Actor) RETURN m,relation,b")
    Collection<Movie> graph();

}
```

And the application.properties

```
spring.data.neo4j.username=neo4j
spring.data.neo4j.password=neo4j
spring.data.neo4j.uri=bolt://localhost:7687
```

NodeEntity of moview

```
@NodeEntity
public class Movie {

    @Id
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String genre;
//    @JsonIgnoreProperties("movie")
    @Relationship(type = "ActedIn")
    private List<Actor> actors;
//    @Relationship(type = "ACTED_IN" , direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
//    private List<Actress> actresses = new ArrayList<>();


    public Movie() {
    }

    public List<Actor> getActors() {
        return actors;
    }

    public void setActors(List<Actor> actors) {
        this.actors = actors;
    }

    public Movie(int id, String title, String genre, List<Actor> actors) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
       this.genre=genre;
       this.actors=actors;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre=genre;
    }


}
```

And NodeEntity of Actor

```
public class Actor {
    @GraphId
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Actor() {
    }

    public Actor(Long id, String name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }



}
```

I also tried springboot + neo4j projects downloaded from github, and also followed the instructions from neo4j website, but the projects still failed on my computer, so is there any super tutorials for neo4j and springboot?

Comment: Could you please add the versions of Spring Boot / Spring Data Neo4j, you are using? I can see by the annotations that you are using Spring Data Neo4j 5.x but I don't know if this was intentionally or not. Also I would like to know which instructions you are referring to. The current intro tutorial here https://neo4j.com/developer/spring-data-neo4j/ uses Spring Data Neo4j 6.